# Aptana customisation : PHP Syntax colours

Tags: aptana

I am rather fond of the Green Chaud set of colourisations for Aptana ( http://gueschla.com/labs/green-chaud./ ), however I notice that the PHP section of options is gone from the `Aptana > Editors` section of the preferences window.

Does anyone know how to colourise the PHP editor now that the option is gone to import a `.col`? I've had a poke in the preferences `PHP > Appearance` section, but no options to colourise in there. Am I doomed to stick with the plain colours?

PS. `Aptana Studio, build: 2.0.4.1268158907` `PDT Dev Tools 2.1.3v20090914`

Comment: I have the same problem.
According to the Aptana site (http://www.aptana.org/php) "Aptana PHP is no longer included in Aptana Studio 2.0, and only PDT will be supported going forward. Developers who wish to continue using Aptana PHP may continue using Aptana Studio 1.5.x for as long as they wish. ".

Comment: It's a shame that the PDT doesn't have the same basic functionality that the Aptana PHP plugin had, even when they say they've merged!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old question, but I found this when searching today, and have just found the solution - maybe it will help others - currently I don't like the visual changes in Aptana 3 beta, but wanted to continue using the Aptana PHP plugin with Studio 2.0.

Anybody using Aptana 2.x can install Aptana PHP manually.... and you'll then be able to theme and import a .col file.

1. Help -> Install New Software
2. Add http://update.aptana.com/install/php as a source
3. Install the plugin.