# How to change the color of PHP syntax in Aptana IDE?

Tags: php, aptana

How do I modify the colors of PHP tags in Aptana? I would like to change the black syntax color to red [as shown in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVAE7.png)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to install the [PHP language plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643958/aptana-customisation-php-syntax-colours) into Aptana.

Once the language support is in place, you should be able to make changes in `Window -> Preferences -> Aptana -> Themes`

Comment: Old topic with 8 years old. There is no solution. is there any way?